# Async function returns undefined type

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, discord.js

I have an async function that makes a call to a database and returns a string (promise). However when I call this function I get undefined

The async function:

```
const SUCCESS = 'Channel storage initialized succesfully';
const FAIL = 'There has been a problem initializng this channel';
const EXISTS = 'Channel already initialized'

initializeChannelDatabase = async channelNum =>{
    const db = admin.firestore();
    db.collection('channels').doc(channelNum).get().then(res=>{
        if(!res.exists){
            db.collection('channels').doc(channelNum).set({isPremium: false}).then(res=>{
                return Promise.resolve(SUCCESS);
            }).catch(err=>{
                return Promise.resolve(FAIL);
            })
        }else{
            return Promise.resolve(EXISTS);
        }
    }).catch(err=>{
        return Promise.resolve(FAIL);
    })
}
```

Then I call this function from here but get undefined in the console:

```
client.on('message', async msg => {
    if(msg.content==='\'init'){
        initializeChannelDatabase(msg.channel.id).then(result=>{
            console.log(result);
            if(result===SUCCESS){
            ...
```

Comment: I have eddited the code to include the strings at the top. I want to return a specific one of them. Ex SUCCESS if .then() gets executed, FAIL if .catch() etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you never return from `initializeChannelDatabase`. The only return statements inside it are placed inside `then` and `catch` callbacks. So they return from the callback function, not from `initializeChannelDatabase`.

Adding a `return` statement before your promise `then`/`catch` chains should solve the problem and return the final promise produced by the promise chain.

```
initializeChannelDatabase = async channelNum => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    return db.collection('channels').doc(channelNum).get().then(res=>{
    // ^ return the promise chain
        if(!res.exists){
            return db.collection('channels').doc(channelNum).set({isPremium: false}).then(res=>{
            // ^ return the nested promise chain
                return Promise.resolve(SUCCESS);
            }).catch(err=>{
                return Promise.resolve(FAIL);
            })
        }else{
            return Promise.resolve(EXISTS);
        }
    }).catch(err=>{
        return Promise.resolve(FAIL);
    })
}
```

However since your function already uses the `async` keyword you might as well use the `await` functionality instead of building a promise chain.

```
initializeChannelDatabase = async channelNum => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    
    try {
        const channel = await db.collection('channels').doc(channelNum).get();
        if (channel.exists) return EXISTS;
        await db.collection('channels').doc(channelNum).set({isPremium: false});
        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (error) {
        return FAIL;
    }
}
```

I would also highly recommend using `thow FAIL/EXISTS` instead of `return FAIL/EXISTS`. This will ensure that the returned promise is rejected. Landing the caller in the alternate `catch` path. If the intent was to merge success and failure together you can leave it as is.

Comment: Hi, be aware that the user whant to return EXISTS when `channel.exists` is true. Good answer anyway :)

Comment: @Drago96 Good spot, forgot the invert the if-statement when converted it to a guard clause. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined because you're not actually returning anything from the `initialiseChannelDatabase` function.

Since you're using async, you should also use 'await' when using asynchronous functions, it will be way easier to handle this situation without additional closures and callbacks:

```
initializeChannelDatabase = async channelNum => {

    const db = admin.firestore();

    try {

        let channelDoc = await db.collection('channels').doc(channelNum).get();
    
        if (!channelDoc.exists) {

            await db.collection('channels').doc(channelNum).set({ isPremium: false });
    
            return SUCCESS;

        } else {
            return EXISTS;
        }

    } catch (err) {
        return FAIL;
    }
}
```

Other information on async / await on [this link](https://javascript.info/async-await)

EDIT: removed the inner try-catch because in the event of failing, it will trigger the first catch and be fine anyway.

Answer (score -2):

You return `Promise.resolve(SUCCESS)` but the variable `SUCCESS`is undefined in your code.
Your intention was probably to return the string `'SUCCESS'` like in the MDN documentation:

```js
Promise.resolve('Success').then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // "Success"
}, function(value) {
  // not called
});
```

Comment: They are defined as strings previously in the code. Sorry for not including that I thought it wasn't necessary